# Custom django tag returning a list?

Tags: python, django

I'd need to create a custom tag returning a list I can then walk through with `{% for item in custom_tag_returning_list %}` .

Now I've made a following hack using *assign_tag* method, but doubt if it's the right way:

```
from django import template
from product.models import Product

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def all_products():
    return Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

In a template I can't use `all_products` directly but need to assign to some variable first:

```
{% all_products as all_products_list %}
{% if all_products_list %}
  {% for product in all_products_list %} 
   ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Is it necessary to do an assignment to a temporary variable ? Can't be used directly with some other tag helper ?

Comment: why can you not send this in the view's context ?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with this? It's exactly what assignment tags are for. Not a hack at all.

Comment: You could do this with a regular tag and an `{% empty %}` tag, but like Daniel says, this looks fine to me.

Comment: @karthikr Probably can but is there some base/general view available to all templates ? Sorry, I'm a newcomer to Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just asking if assignment to some unneeded variable is necessary, feels like a workaround.

Comment: Yeah. I see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Torimus Hello are you sure about this line?
 
`@register.assignment_tag`

I couldn't find any reference to this method in Django's documentation. Maybe you meant this?

`@register.simple_tag`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine to me.

Alternatively, for some reason if you cannot pass the `product_list` through the view's context, you can use an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) if you feel that is cleaner:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("tags/products_list.html")
def all_products():
    return {'products_list': Product.objects.order_by('name') }
```

products_list.html

```
{% for product in products_list %} 
   .........
{% empty %}
  Empty list
{% endfor %}
```

and in the html file, you would just do

```
{% all_products %}
```

Comment: Think you mean `{% for product in product_list %}` based on the dictionary you returned.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate way, probably a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Common approach would be to simply pass `all_products` from the controller in the view context.