# Received too many positional arguments

Tags: python, django

My rango_template_tags.py file:-

```
from django import template
from rango.models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('rango/cats.html')
def get_category_list(cat=None):
    return {'cats':Category.objects.all(),'act_cat': cat}
```

My base.html file:-

```
{% block sidebar_block %}
        {% get_category_list category %}
    {% endblock %}
```

i am getting the error :-

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'get_category_list' received too many positional arguments
```

what is the error in this?

Comment: The code you posted looks ok. Please show the *full* traceback. Are you sure you saved your files and restarted the Django server after updating the code?

Comment: @Alasdair i am trying to paste full traceback but it looks ugly. how can i paste it in a readable manner?

Comment: @Alasdair i saved the files and restarted the server.

Comment: On Django's yellow error page, you can click a button to display the traceback for copy/paste.

Comment: @Alasdair http://dpaste.com/1FBJKKP

Comment: what exactly is category in your template?

Comment: I had the same issue..
Check out this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837271/custom-django-tag-returning-a-list